# What is the meaning of "great with it"?

Tags: meaning, reflexive-pronouns

What is the meaning of "you were great with it" in the following sentence,

> "Your board is totally awesome! I have to get mine in shape," X said,
>   looking at his old orange board. "I think **you were great with it**,"
>   said Charlie. "See you around!"

? (Source: Skateboard moves by MATT CHRISTOPHER)

Does it mean " you were great because of having your board" or "your board that you have is very good board" ?

Does "I have to get mine in shape" mean "I want to buy a good board" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above.

In this context, "You were great with it" means "Your skateboarding was great (when you were skateboarding with your board)".  This statement does not say whether "You were great because of it" or "Your were great despite it".  It does imply that the skateboard is at least minimally adequate.  It is also possible that the speaker was "just being polite" -- the speaker might agree that the skateboard needs to be fixed up, but wanted to end the conversation on a positive note.

"I have to get mine in shape" means "I want (very much) to improve my skateboard so that it is in good shape".  These improvements might require fixing or modifying the skateboard.